# How is a Dataflow pipeline written in Python scheduled via a Cloud Function?

Tags: python, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-functions

[This article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions) explains how you can execute a pipeline written in java via a Cloud Function. However, I'm trying to accomplish this with a pipeline written in python.

I'm able to do this successfully when executing a local Cloud Function using a virtualenv environment for python. This is before being packaged up as a zip.

```
exports.foo = function(event, callback) {
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn(
    'ENV/bin/python',
    ["pipeline.py", 
    "--project $PROEJCT_ID", 
    "--temp_location gs://$BUCKET/temp", 
    "--staging_location gs://$BUCKET/staging", 
    "--runner DataflowRunner"],
    {cwd: __dirname}
);
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});
child.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    callback();
});
```

};

Though, when I do the actual deployment of the Function to GCP and run from there, the pipeline never executes.

Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Below is from the logs when running a deployed Function:

```
D      foo   vxvt93uc415v    2017-03-05 00:56:43.639  Function execution started
D      foo   vxvt93uc415v    2017-03-05 00:56:57.945  Function execution took 14308 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

UPDATE:

There was an error that I wasn't logging out correctly:

```
ENV/bin/python is not a supported ELF or interpreter script
```

I've reached out to the Cloud Functions team who then filed a bug report.

Comment: One of the issues is that Python does not take parameters in the form `--a=b`; but rather in the form `--a b`, without an equal sign. Also, the parameter is `--staging_location`, not `--stage_location`. Perhaps this will help?

Comment: Pablo, thanks for pointing those things out! But, even with those adjustments the problem still stands.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Were you able to trigger it? If yes, Can you update answer?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a binary that had been compiled for MacOS.  The cloud functions container uses Debian, and linux and MacOS executables are not compatible (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9439548).

I installed the [Cloud functions docker container](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docker/blob/master/base/Dockerfile), and downloaded and compiled the binary that I needed inside the container, then copied it out of the container and deployed it with the cloud function.  But you may be able to get away with just using a precompiled Debian-compatible python interpreter in your case.